# Check that a string is not a reserved word?

Tags: cmake

In CMake, given a list of arguments, how can we check if an argument represents a reserved word?

For a concrete example, consider this wrapper around `target_link_libraries()`, which modifies library names but not reserved keywords like `INTERFACE`:

```
macro(modify_library_names LIB_NAMES TO_APPEND OUTPUT_LIST)
foreach(item ${LIB_NAMES})
    if (${item} MATCHES "INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE")
        list(APPEND ${OUTPUT_LIST} "${item}")
    else()
        list(APPEND ${OUTPUT_LIST} "${item}${TO_APPEND}")
    endif()
endforeach()
endmacro()

function(target_link_libraries_multiplexed BASE-NAME)
set(LINK_ARG_SOFT "")
modify_library_names("${ARGN}" "_soft" LINK_ARG_SOFT)
set(LINK_ARG_HARD "")
modify_library_names("${ARGN}" "_hard" LINK_ARG_HARD)

target_link_libraries(${BASE-NAME}_soft
    ${LINK_ARG_SOFT}
)
target_link_libraries(${BASE-NAME}_hard
    ${LINK_ARG_HARD}
)
endfunction()

# Usage:
target_link_libraries_multiplexed(util
    PUBLIC
        math  # links util_soft against math_soft and util_hard against math_hard
)
```

Is there something like `if (RESERVED(item))` that would let us get rid of the hardcoded keyword list on line 3?

Comment: In CMake there is no such thing like "reserved word". A function or a macro may recognize **keyword**(s) among its parameters, but that keyword(s) are chosen specifically by a function. Functions and macros which are [built-in](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-commands.7.html) into CMake and ones which are provided by the [modules shipped with CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-modules.7.html) tend to use upper-case-only strings as keywords. But no one forces custom functions and macros to follow that tendency.

Comment: It seems you are actually looking for a way to **parse arguments** for your function `target_link_libraries_multiplexed`. For that purpose CMake provides the command [cmake_parse_arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_parse_arguments.html). E.g. you could call (inside the function's body) `cmake_parse_arguments("multiplexed" "" "" "PUBLIC;PRIVATE;INTERFACE" ${ARGN})`, so all PUBLIC items will be collected into the list named `multiplexed_PUBLIC` and all PRIVATE items will be collected into the list named `multiplexed_PRIVATE`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I see, ```target_link_libraries``` and similar are treated as plain functions, not as a special language construct. I don't need ```cmake_parse_arguments``` because I just forward the arguments to the inbuilt cmake function which has the same calling convention and parses them properly on its own (the code in the example works as-is).  The goal is to future-proof it by using some CMake-provided list of special values instead of a hardcoded matcher, similar to the documented ```COMMAND``` and ```POLICY``` checks. Too bad that it doesn't exist!